# GwtBootstrap3 FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, gwtbootstrap3

1. Is it possible to disable header for FullCalendar in GwtBoostrap3 ?
   When I use

   Header headerDisabled = new Header();
    headerDisabled.setNoHeader();
    GeneralDisplay gd = new GeneralDisplay();
    gd.setHeader(header);

then the header is still displayed :(
I also tried

```
CalendarConfig config = new CalendarConfig(headerDisabled);
```

it didnt work.

2. I implemented the Method `public void dayRender(JavaScriptObject javaScriptObject, Element element)`
   in

   gd.setViewRenderCallback(new ViewRenderCallback()

but this method is never called. I would like to update the height of the cells. Any idea how can I do it else?

thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, for your header issue, in the JS plugin we can hide the header by setting confing : `header: false,`. In the gwt wrapper, i think you can do the same by using `CalendarConfig config = new CalendarConfig(null);`

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your answer. I already tried to set null into CalendarConfig, but it didnt work.
some other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found how to workaround.

First, it seems this is a bug of FullCalendar `Header` which setting `null` instead of `false` when calling `setNoHeader();`.

**The workaround :**

Create your custom header :

```
public class MyHeader extends Header {
    @Override
    public native void setNoHeader() /*-{
        var theInstance = this;
        theInstance.@org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.fullcalendar.client.ui.Header::header = false;
    }-*/;
}
```

And build your FullCalendar :

```
MyHeader header = new MyHeader();
header.setNoHeader();
CalendarConfig conf = new CalendarConfig(header);
FullCalendar c = new FullCalendar("toto", ViewOption.agendaDay, conf, true);
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Cool, thank you now the header is not visible any more. thank you very much.

Comment: do you now when the callback for dayRender should be called?
I would like to change the hight for the cells in my calendar.
So I tried to do following:
 @Override
            public void dayRender(JavaScriptObject javaScriptObject, Element element) {
                log.info("I'm in DayRender");
                element.getStyle().setHeight(new Double(3).doubleValue(), Style.Unit.EM);
            }
when I start the calendar, this method never used. doesnt matter what I'm doing, this method is not called.

Comment: I don't know because i never used FullCalendar, but i think you can do it in pure CSS by using `.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {height: 3em;}` but it should be another question ;). Good news it works for your Header, don't forget to mark as aswered, it could help more people ;)

Comment: you are right, I should mark it as answered. BUT how can I do it? I dont see any button answered here :(

Comment: It should have a "check" at the top left of my anwser. [More Information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)